# How to write expect statement for new keyword using EasyMock?

Tags: new-operator, easymock

I want to write expect statement for line **filter = new Simple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);** using EasyMock only.

```
//SingleLimit.java
private Limitation filter;

protected final Limitation getBaseLimitation() {
    Validate.notNull(type);
    GroupClass Group = new GroupClass(GroupTypeClass.SELECTOR);
    if (Activatable.class.isAssignableFrom(typeListed)) {
        if (A.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        //expect statement for below line
        filter = new Simple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE); 
        }
     }
    }


   //Simple.java
   public class Simple implements Serializable, Limitation
   {
     public Simple(String path, Operator operator, Object value) {
    this(path, operator, new Object[]{value});
   }
    }
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new class that creates Simple objects.

```
public class SimpleFactory {
    public Simple createSimple(....) {
        return new Simple(....);
    }
}
```

Than incject this factory into your class or pass it as parameter

```
public YourClazz(SimpleFactory simpleFactory) {

    //constructor 
    this.simpleFactory = simpleFactory;

    protected final Limitation getBaseLimitation() {
        ///...
        //filter = new Simple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);
        //change this to
        filter = simpleFactory.createSimple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    //or pass as parameter
    protected final Limitation getBaseLimitation(SimpleFactory simpleFacotry) {
        ///...
        //filter = new Simple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);
        //change this to
        filter = simpleFactory.createSimple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);
    }    
}
```

Now in your test code create a mock of simpleFactory.

//edited 2019/11/16 another solution

If you can not create other class, create new method in your class, then use it for creating new Simple object:

```
    public YourClazz {

        protected Simple createSimple(....) {
            return new Simple(....);
        }

        protected final Limitation getBaseLimitation() {
            //...
            //filter = new Simple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);
            //change this to
            filter = createSimple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE);
    //...
        }    
}
```

Now for testing you can create a partial mock of your class and mock createSimple method:

```
YourClazz mock = partialMockBuilder(YourClazz.class)
      .addMockedMethod("createSimple").createMock();


Simple expectedSimple = new Simple(....);      

expect(mock.createSimple(.....).andReturn(expectedSimple);
replay(mock);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. But, I cannot create new class as per your suggestion. It's a restriction.

Comment: Many Thanks, I have mentioned in the code snippet about behavior of "new Simple()". It is a constructor of class "Simple.java".

Comment: You can not mock contructor using EasyMock. The only way to solve your problem is to refactor your code to use some method for creating Simple objects and mock this method in your tests.